# Missing support tools for Android Studio Flamingo: how can I include find places on map feature in my app?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-support-library

I am trying to create an android application that includes find places on map, for that i might need to have the support tools downloaded, but i cannot find the support tools through the SDK tools. I am using Android Studio Flamingo.

I noticed when i tried to put this in the XML"        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
"